# BackBone first click doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

Event does not work when first time clicking on the element, second click works as expected

**Namespaces:**

```
var goose = goose || {
    Models: {},
    Views: {},
    Collections: {},
    Routes: {}
};
```

**Collection**, where I use filter for data:

```
goose.Collections.CollectionChannels = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: goose.Models.ModelChannel,
    localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage("Channels"),
    fetch: function(options) {
        // check if localStorage for this collection exists
        if(!localStorage.getItem("Channels")) {
            var self = this;
            // fetch from server once
            $.ajax({
                url: 'json/channels.json'
            }).done(function(response) {
                $.each(response, function(i, item) {
                    self.create(item);  // saves model to local storage
                });
            });
        } else {
            // call original fetch method
            return Backbone.Collection.prototype.fetch.call(this, options);
        }
    },
    byFilter: function(filter, value) {
        var _this = this, f;
        this.fetch({success: function() {
            f = _this.filter(function(model) {
                return model.get(filter) == value;
            }); 
        }, 
        error: 
            function() {
                alert("Ошибка, обновите страницу.");
            }
        });
        return new goose.Collections.CollectionChannels(f);
    }
});
```

**View, set event:**

```
goose.Views.ViewСhannel = Backbone.View.extend({
    id: "item",
    template: _.template($("#news_item").html()),
    initialize: function() {
        this.listenTo(this.model, "change", this.render);
        this.render();
    },
    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    },
   events: {
       "click .favor" : "addToFavor"
   },
   addToFavor: function() {
       this.model.set("favorite", !this.model.get("favorite"));
       this.model.save();
   }
});
```

**Initialize view and add collection after filter:**

```
goose.Views.viewСhannels = new goose.Views.ViewСhannels({
     collection: goose.Collections.collectionchannels.byFilter("cat", "news"),
     el: ".news .content"
});
```

Comment: Are you attaching your view to existing markup to start?

Comment: I use undescore's template 
<script type="txt/template" id="news_item">
<div id="item"><%= title %> - <span class="favor"><%= favorite %></span></div></script> and add compile template add to the DOM (<div class="channels">
   <div class="channel sport">
    <a href="#">Channels</a>
    <div class="content"></div>
   </div>
  </div>)

Comment: What I mean is does the markup you use to attach the view to already exist when you instantiate the view? Since you're specifying a selector for your el, then the view is expecting the markup to already be there.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what "does not work"?  Is the event handler being called?  Is the model being set>  Is it being saved?  Also you may want to provide the definition of your `Model` class, or at least its `defaults`.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. In the first click the checkbox is not getting marked but the event is getting fired. In the first occurrence the checkbox goes with a false value and in the second true.